# Is there a common term used for a collection of synthesized user research and testing data for a company?

Tags: user-research, terminology, usability-testing

The term knowledgebase is common used to describe a collection or repository of information or data that is available to draw on. For most companies this only applies to external or public facing areas of the website where users or customers contribute to a pool of knowledge.

However, I am wondering if there is an accepted term for an internal facing repository of synthesized data (e.g. personas, user journeys, testing data) that UX designers draw on to make design decisions. Would the term 'user knowledgebase' make sense in this case?

Answer (score 3):

I generally call those things in whole a "design strategy" and individually "design strategy assets". But I think everyone has their own terms for it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the term used for the user research & usability testing results can vary depending on how you choose to store and synthesize data.

If you use a software program, data can be grouped in data collection, database.

The result can be a report, a graphic.

The knowledge base is the technology used to store all the information, but you asked for a term for the synthesized data and this is different, in my opinion.

Please check [this article on Nielsen Norman Group](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/archiving-usability-reports/):

> I recently asked 245 usability practitioners what they do with their
>   old user testing reports. Their answers were as follows:
>
> 12% keep reports in a knowledge base ;
>
> 27% keep reports in a single online document collection ;
>
> 29% keep reports online in various locations , so they have to track
>   down reports when they need them; and
>
> 33% don't keep old usability reports online at all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any specific term for this. It seems to me that this is largely dependant on organisational practice, methodology and the needs of specific audiences within the organisation.

I have used the term "ux assets". This being said I view a pattern library as "binding agent" that brings together and links to a range of user experience documentation and reports in coherent and more structured approach.

Comment: I am curious as to why there isn't a term that differentiate between the collective 'insights' from doing the research and testing versus the output of the various ux activities like wireframes, user journeys and even the competitive analysis or eye tracking. There should be some term for the synthesized information about users that is used to made design decisions don't you think?